# Samsung galaxy note 3 not accessing external memory

Tags: android

We have an application built in android and just for a phone we can't acces the photos from external memory. What should be the problem? From the phone or from the application?

For every other phones we tested it is working to acces the photo galery, but for this one it is not working...

Comment: Kitkat? There's a lot out there about apps not being able to *write* to sd card folders after updating to kitkat. But at least BBM for android had until recently an issue with *reading* photos from sd card, so it's not just you. I don't know more though.

Comment: Yes. 4.4.2 is the android version